# Synchronized data extension has not been added to Data Designer

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, data-designer

I am using EDA (Education Data Architecture) in Salesforce. I have synchronized a bunch of objects to marketing cloud. All the objects are successfully synced and all (except one) have been automatically added to Data Designer.

[image: hed__Application__c object successfully synced]

The problem object is the hed__Application__c object. This has a lookup relationship to Contact in salesforce (via the hed__Applicant__c field, which is one of the fields being synced to MC).

I have a bunch of other hed__ objects synced to marketing cloud and these are correctly added to data designer automatically. But the hed__Application__c synced DE is not there.

I first synced this object months ago and have tried refreshing the object from the synchronized DE setup area. Still not showing.

[image: Contact Data Designer]

The only thing I can think of is that the hed__Application__c object has TWO lookup relationships to the Contact object. I don't think that should matter??

Interestingly, the hed__Application__c object DOES show under the User data designer view:

[image: User Data Designer]

Anyone know why this particular object would not be added to data designer when all the other ones are?

Answer (score 0):

There is a priority to the SFDC relationships that get honored in SFMC Sync'd Data that isn't exactly explained anywhere. Their documentation here outlines that: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_synch_object_relationship_priority.htm&type=5

You might be better off with an hourly SQL Query copy/paste of the 'hed__Application__c' object data then building it in it's own Contact Data Attribute Group if you need that Contact > hed__Application__c explicit relationship.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure that is relevant though as it is referring to User and other objects. But in my case the link to Contact is missing. A good comparison is the hed__Affiliation__c custom object you can see in both Contact and User screenshots above. Why did that object appear for both User and Contact, whereas the hed__Application__c object is missing for Contact.

Comment: You would have to plug into the Data Relationships on the SFDC side and see those connections better. I've done it many years ago, but haven't touched it in a while.

So what is happening is that for whatever reason in SFDC the 'Affiliation' object has relationships to both Contact and User that it sees as 'primary', but on your 'Application' object it is prioritizing the User object relationship and none this is documented well in their Help section. Are either of your Contact relationship fields between Contact <> Application required fields on the Application object records?

Comment: There are two Contact lookup fields on the Application object. Neither are required. But I think maybe the fact there are two is the problem. I’ve never seen this happen before though so not sure. Having said that, I’ve had my fair share of “weird undocumented” behaviour in marketing cloud so it wouldn’t surprise me if this is just some weird behaviour/bug. I’m tempted to unsync and resync the Application object to try and force it to remap but there is too much potential to break stuff. So a custom DE and custom data mapping it is :(